# How to append a single object into the object of array?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use `$date_wise=DB::select('')`  in laravel 5.4 controller
the `$date_wise` returns :

```
  array:8 [▼
  0 => {#740 ▼
    +"justManifest": 230045
    +"manifes_no": "230045/6/2017"
    +"total_truck": "6"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 3.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "2001"
    +"truck_type": "NBJH"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "567767878"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:36"
  }
  1 => {#742 ▼
    +"justManifest": 890
    +"manifes_no": "890/3/2017"
    +"total_truck": "3"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 0.0
    +"cargo_name": "Baby Texi, Three Wheeler, Scooter, Motor Cycle & Motor Car Tyre & Tube(Size: Below-700)"
    +"truck_no": "7654"
    +"truck_type": "WB"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "8765"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:37"
  }
  2 => {#744 ▼
    +"justManifest": 890
    +"manifes_no": "890/3/2017"
    +"total_truck": "3"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 0.0
    +"cargo_name": "Baby Texi, Three Wheeler, Scooter, Motor Cycle & Motor Car Tyre & Tube(Size: Below-700)"
    +"truck_no": "78631"
    +"truck_type": "WB"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "6543"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:40"
  }
  3 => {#743 ▼
    +"justManifest": 230045
    +"manifes_no": "230045/6/2017"
    +"total_truck": "6"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 3.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "3001"
    +"truck_type": "NBJK"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "4567890"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:48"
  }
  4 => {#747 ▼
    +"justManifest": 45777
    +"manifes_no": "45777/A/2017"
    +"total_truck": "A"
    +"total_truck_entered": 1
    +"remaining_trucks": -1.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "1009"
    +"truck_type": "BNDE"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "4567890"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:35:52"
  }
  5 => {#748 ▼
    +"justManifest": 230045
    +"manifes_no": "230045/6/2017"
    +"total_truck": "6"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 3.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "4001"
    +"truck_type": "BHUI"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "877788"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:36:44"
  }
  6 => {#746 ▼
    +"justManifest": 890
    +"manifes_no": "890/3/2017"
    +"total_truck": "3"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 0.0
    +"cargo_name": "Baby Texi, Three Wheeler, Scooter, Motor Cycle & Motor Car Tyre & Tube(Size: Below-700)"
    +"truck_no": "8743"
    +"truck_type": "WB"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "8776"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 12:42:28"
  }
  7 => {#749 ▼
    +"justManifest": 2510
    +"manifes_no": "2510/A/2017"
    +"total_truck": "A"
    +"total_truck_entered": 1
    +"remaining_trucks": -1.0
    +"cargo_name": "RAW COTTON"
    +"truck_no": "123"
    +"truck_type": "WB"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "987654321"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 16:33:05"
  }
]
```

how can i push index no 3 to index no 1?
I want `justmanifest`_no 230045 in serial. all same `justmanifest` no will be is a serial.
How can i do in php?
I tried:
I loop the object using foreach then take the unique in new object. when no 3 comes with same `justmanifest`no 230045 i tried to append it in no. 0. but can not find any method to append object's specific index.

Expected Output:

```
    array:8 [▼
  0 => {#740 ▼
    +"justManifest": 230045
    +"manifes_no": "230045/6/2017"
    +"total_truck": "6"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 3.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "2001"
    +"truck_type": "NBJH"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "567767878"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:36"
  }
  1 => {#743 ▼
    +"justManifest": 230045
    +"manifes_no": "230045/6/2017"
    +"total_truck": "6"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 3.0
    +"cargo_name": "Fruit and vegetables"
    +"truck_no": "3001"
    +"truck_type": "NBJK"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "4567890"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:48"
  }

  2 => {#742 ▼
    +"justManifest": 890
    +"manifes_no": "890/3/2017"
    +"total_truck": "3"
    +"total_truck_entered": 3
    +"remaining_trucks": 0.0
    +"cargo_name": "Baby Texi, Three Wheeler, Scooter, Motor Cycle & Motor Car Tyre & Tube(Size: Below-700)"
    +"truck_no": "7654"
    +"truck_type": "WB"
    +"created_by": "truck"
    +"driver_card": "8765"
    +"truckentry_datetime": "2017-10-25 09:34:37"
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "push 3 in 2"? can you be more specific please..

Comment: i mean index shown in image. how can i push no. 3 index in no.1 as both has same justmanifest no-230045?

Comment: ah, you wanna replace them? Example 3 with 1?

Comment: I like images but not when they contain code. Use copy & paste and post the code/data, not an image of it.

Comment: i like to place no. 3 index in after o index. @vural

Comment: notice both index(0 and 3) have same "justmanifest". I want them in same sequence @VuralAcar

Comment: I took the image from dd() output @axiac

Comment: i did what you suggested @axiac

Comment: That's better. It doesn't help for this question but keep in mind that an image of code doesn't help. Post the code or the data you need processed to help those that can help you.